# Graphing polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I'm trying to learn to factor polynomials, and I'm trying to graph

$$30x^5 – 166x^4 – 542x^3 + 2838x^2 + 1520x – 800$$

from [here](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/solvpoly2.htm) on Purplemath.

When I graph polynomials on my NSpire CS CAX or [here](http://www.meta-calculator.com/online/) it doesn't match up with what the picture gives. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We have no way of knowing what you're doing wrong if you don't tell us what you did. Are you sure you entered it correctly? Are you sure the axes match?

Comment: You should play a little with the "Y-Scale" button.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan I entered the equation in and told it to graph.

Comment: @CrewdNBasic I did too and it worked fine for me.

Comment: What PurpleMath gave was right. Check http://snipurl.com/23bm97v

Answer (score 1):

You should probably set `Y-min` to `–1000` and `Y-max` to `10000` or something like that. That's most likely the problem, but I'm not completely sure because I can't see what you've done exactly.